# regex: Match word only when another word is not present

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/TMUMkH/2)

```
/^(?!(.*(Ink|Cartridge).*))(?:.*(\b - Black$\b))/
```

Below are my samples

```
no match string
Simple match string - Black
Unmatched line with lowercase - black
Unmatched line with the word Ink within - Black
Unmatched line with the word Cartridge within - Black
Unmatched line with the string' - Black' before the end
```

My regex matches the entire line 2, but I am trying to match just the word 
 ' - Black' at the end of the string and not the entire string.

The regular expression syntax should be based on JavaScript regular expressions.

any ideas?

Comment: And what is the final result? Are you replacing or extracting? Look, you [have already *captured* the value](https://regex101.com/r/8LsoTQ/1). What else do you need?

Comment: As @WiktorStribiżew said you're capturing that value into capture group 3. In other regex flavours this is possible using the `\K` token to reset the match, or use variable length positive lookbehinds (even less support), or even have regex use a reversed string, but JavaScript doesn't have this. The only way you can achieve this in JavaScript without using capture groups is to reverse the string first, then perform regex on it and use a positive lookahead as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/TMUMkH/3) with `kcalB - (?=.*(?:egdirtraC|knI))`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match the word '-Black' only, the correct regex would be:

```
/- Black/
```

The regex above just matches `- Black` as asked by the question.

However, indeed you have more needs than "matching `- Black` ", rather you want

> all occurrences of the string `- Black` only when its underlying sentence does not contain `Ink` nor `Cartridge`, and only if `- Black` is at the end of the sentence and not `- black` (lowercase)

Now, if you just want what I exposed, it is not a problem for you to match ALL the sentence at the same time as the desired `- Black` string. In fact, this is what `capturing` is for in the regex world. The parenthesis `(` and `)` you put in your regex actually "grabs/takes/captures" what's in it for you and STORES it in a variable for later use.

This means :

```
/hello (world)/
```

would MATCH `hello world` but CAPTURE only `world`. This capture goes into a variable named `group`, and here I have only one group, so `world` would be stored in the group number `1`.

In order to CALL this group for other purpose (storing/deleting/replacing), you need to write a dollar sign `$` followed by the number of the desired group (here `1`). For this example, `$1` should output `world`. So this is how you can MATCH something while CAPTURING another.

Thus, coming back to your example. I would suggest you do something like:

```
/^(?!(?:.*(?:Ink|Cartridge).*))(?:.*(?: (- Black)$))/gm
```

Look at this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/GmDHsP/1), open the `substitution` tab below the examples, and try to write `$1`: there you have it,

> just `- Black`.

Then it's up to you to do something with `$1`.